# jquery: How to get attribute value with other attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a data-ca-action="1427202" title="deneme123">deneme123</a>
```

I need get data-ca-action value (1427202) with title value (deneme123) how can I do this with jquery?

I'm try this: `$("a").$("[title=deneme123]")` but I need more detail because I can't set up the logic of the code I need to write

Comment: `$("a[title=deneme123]").data("caAction")`

Answer (score 0):

something like that

```js
const res = $("a[title='deneme121']").data('ca-action')
$('#resultView').text(`$("a[title=\'deneme121\']").data(\'ca-action\') -> ${res}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none">
  <a data-ca-action="1427202_1" title="deneme121">deneme121_text</a>
  <a data-ca-action="1427202_2" title="deneme122">deneme122_text</a>
  <a data-ca-action="1427202_3" title="deneme123">deneme123_text</a>
</div>

<div id="resultView"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr`

```
JQuery('a[title="deneme123"]').attr('data-ca-action')
```

[See this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp)